# Настройка маршрутов на CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, маршрутизация

Помогите с настройкой конфигурации на CentOS 6.

Итак, что имеем.

1. В офисе стоит HUB провайдера. На один из портов предоставили SIP услугу.
   (Это не интернет доступ)

   IP Address: 31.7.aaa.bbb.
   Netmask: 255.255.255.128
   Gateway: 31.7.aaa.ccc
   Username: aaaaaa
   Pass: bbbbbb
2. В оффисе есть АТС, где я записываю:

   Username: aaaaaa
   Pass: bbbbbb

от SIP провайдера.

```
Настройки АТС:
IPADDRESS: 10.10.10.2
MASK: 255..255.255.0
Gateway: 10.10.10.1
```

3. Есть компьютер с CentOS 6.

   eth0 - стоят IP SIP
   eth1 - стоит 10.10.10.1

Роуты сделал SIP регистрируется и работает нормально.

Вопрос:

Добавить третью сетевую карту eth2 с настройками от провайдера, предоставляющего интернет.

```
IPADDRESS: 212.42.aaa.bbb
NETMASK: 255.255.255.240
GATEWAY: 212.42.aaa.ccc.
```

и чтобы АТС подключенный в eth1 (10.10.10.1) лазил в интернет через eth2.
Но чтобы SIP регистрация осталась. как описано через eth0.

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0):

На центоси прописать маршрут 31.7.aaa.bbb/255.255.255.128 через 31.7.aaa.ccc, а default через 212.42.aaa.ccc.

При правильно настроенных фаерволлах и NAT'ах заработает сразу и автомагически.